# Unable to create subscription for topic

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am trying my hands on google deployment manager.

I have created a YAML file where I am creating a topic and a push subscription for the topic.

```
resources:
  - name: pubsub-topic
    type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics
    properties:
      topic: "topic-01"
  - name: pubsub-sub
    type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.subscriptions
    properties:
      subscription: "gcf-01"
      topic: "projects/my-project/topics/topic-01"
      pushConfig: 
        pushEndpoint: "https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld/"
      ackDeadlineSeconds: 600
      expirationPeriod:
```

When I run the command

```
cloud deployment-manager deployments create google-pub-sub --config C:\Development\GCP\DeploymentManager.yaml
```

I get the following error

> The fingerprint of the deployment is xxxxxxxxxxxxx== Waiting
>   for create
>   [operation-xxxxxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx]...failed.
>   ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.create) Error in
>   Operation [operation-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx]:
>   errors:
>   - code: RESOURCE_ERROR   location: /deployments/google-pub-sub/resources/pubsub-sub   message:
>   '{"ResourceType":"gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.subscriptions","ResourceErrorCode":"404","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":404,"message":"Resource
>       not found (resource=topic-01).","status":"NOT_FOUND","details":[],"statusMessage":"Not
>       Found","requestPath":"https://pubsub.googleapis.com/v1/projects/my-project/subscriptions/gcf-01","httpMethod":"PUT"}}'

Now If I run the command

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments update google-pub-sub --config C:\Development\GCP\DeploymentManager.yaml
```

it works. Does this means that the operations are not sequential and system is trying to create subscription before the topic is created.

Also I am still not able to set the ExpirationPeriod to Never. If some one knows then do let me know.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I solved the first issue by using the references in YAML file, so the changed file looks like

```
resources:
  - name: pubsub-topic
    type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.topics
    properties:
      topic: "topic-01"
  - name: pubsub-sub
    type: gcp-types/pubsub-v1:projects.subscriptions
    properties:
      subscription: "gcf-01"
      topic: $(ref.pubsub-topic.name)
      pushConfig: 
        pushEndpoint: "https://us-central1-my-project.cloudfunctions.net/helloWorld/"
      ackDeadlineSeconds: 600
      expirationPolicy: {}
```

Comment: As far as I remember, Deployment Manager property reference matches the API reference. If you check [here](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.subscriptions/create) it stands for `expirationPolicy` object, with `ttl` content

Comment: @manasouza thanks for the reply. I can use ttl to set the expiration period but I want to set it to never expires. If I leave ttl blank it causes error, if I set it to "never" it fails and if I simply remove it then it fails as well.

Comment: if i only specify expirationPolicy and dont specify ttl then I get following error `- code: CONDITION_NOT_MET
  location: /deployments/google-pub-sub/resources/ct-pubsub-orders-sub->$.properties
  message: '"/expirationPolicy": domain: validation; keyword: type; message: instance
    does not match any allowed primitive type; allowed: ["object"]; found: "null"'`

Comment: as per the link, If ttl is not set, the associated resource never expires but this doesn't seems to be working.